# How to run just jekyll on a specific folder in WIndows 10?I can run bundle exec jekyll

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

I've just reinstalled jekyll after updating ruby using rubyinstaller, and then ran gem install jekyll bundler, with everything installing fine. After that when I run just jekyll in "My Directory" I get the following error message. If I run bundle exec jekyll everything works as expected. Also, if I run jekyll in a different directory it also runs fine. I would like to run just jekyll in "my directory" too. How to do it ?
Below is the error message I'm getting.

```
jekyll
Traceback (most recent call last):
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.1.1/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.1.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:52:in `require_from_bundler'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `setup'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `map'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:147:in `each'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:147:in `each'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:312:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated mercenary 0.4.0, but your Gemfile requires mercenary 0.3.6. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get errors like "You have already activated $OLD_GEM, but your Gemfile requires $NEW_GEM," it is telling you some of the gems you have installed are old or otherwise different than what was expected. You can usually fix this by running `bundle update`. If that fails, try deleting your Gemfile.lock file and running `bundle install`.

A different "solution" could be to alias `bundle exec jekyll build`, but I'm not sure if Windows has aliases.

Comment: Hi, I tried to delete the lock file and ran bundle install, but it shows the same error.

Comment: You might try `gem uninstall mercenary --version 0.4.0`. Does `gem which mercenary` work in Windows? That should return the location of the library. I'm wondering if your PATH has the old location and therefore the old gems. `gem environment` should give you even more details about which gems you have installed. You might need to make changes to your PATH depending on what you find there.

Comment: when I run gem `uninstall mercenary --version 0.4.0` I get a warning saying jekyll-4.1.1 depends on it. If I try to uninstall jekyll-4.1.1 and then mercenary 0.4.0, then I can run just jekyll again. I guess that I am sticking with this (4.0.1) version for now.

Comment: If it were me, at this point, I'd delete/uninstall Ruby and start from scratch. You could possibly figure this out but it won't be worth the time. With a fresh install you could be running perfectly in under an hour.

But for completeness/posterity, you can uninstall gems no matter their warning. When you run `bundle install` it will add back any dependencies. Which based on what you've said makes me wonder what is in your Gemfile.

You might have better luck sorting this by asking in the [Jekyll Forums](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/) or some Ruby spesific forum.